# Eliminar CSS o JS innecesario Joomla

Tags: css, optimización, joomla3, component

Buscando optimizar la carga de mi sitio web, quiero saber si es posible eliminar o filtrar la carga de ciertos archivos .css y .js que se añaden de forma automática desde el jdoc:include type="component". Uso Joomla 3.

Ejemplo: Si entro a la vista de un producto en un componente de ecommercce como virtuemart, no debería cargarme los css y js de otros componentes como un K2 que es para mostrar artículos y no tiene nada que ver con la tienda y viceversa.

Espero hacerme enteder. Gracias

Comment: No es así como funciona. El navegador cachea los ficheros descargados, por lo que es mejor que los descargue todos una vez y que no lo vuelva a hacer.

Answer (score 0):

La primer recomendación sería tratar de usar la menor cantidad de extensiones posible, ya que es común que cada extensión incluya sus propios archivos, para el resto:

Puedes hacer uso de alguna extensión como [JSpeed](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/core-enhancements/performance/jspeed/) o [JHC Optimize](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jch-optimize/), la versión gratuita de JHC te permite:

- Combinar archivos Js en un sólo archivo *(una sola petición)*.
- Combinar archivos CSS en un sólo archivo *(una sola petición)*.

Hasta este punto, debes realizar pruebas, ya que es posible que se genere algún error *(no puede ser automático porque depende de la configuración de cada sitio)*, si esto pasa, también cuenta con una opción para excluir archivos, de modo que solo puedas combinar los necesarios.

- Puedes diferir la carga de archivos Js o moverlos al final de la página para optimizar la carga.

Algunas plantillas hacen uso de un framework, de modo que es posible que tu sitio ya incluya alguna opción similar, revisa sus opciones en **Extensiones** > **Plantillas** > **Estilos** > **Tu Plantilla**.

Encuentra más extensiones en el directorio oficial:
https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/performance/